# Looking for a fic where Harry attempts suicide and the order gets notified for underage magic

Tags: story-identification, harry-potter, fan-fiction

Basically Harry (either end of 4th or 5th year) tries to kill himself using sectumsempra but the order gets notified for underage magic, and finds him. Remus featured pretty heavily in the story and I believe I got to it by searching `suicide+harry/remus`, `suicidal harry/remus` or `depression/depressed harry/remus` but I've fairly extensively searched through all of them and no luck. Read on ao3 around 1-2 years ago.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you read this?

Comment: Read it on ao3 i think, would’ve been about two-ish years ago so wouldn’t be surprised if it got taken down

Comment: @user165864 could you please [edit] your question to add those details?